# How to merge array of objects with same key

Tags: javascript

I have one array with multiple object,want to merge them by same keys without losing their values.

I try some of answer in stakoverflow but none of them help me.i want to do this with map/reduce but i don't know how can i retrieve key name of every object to check them.

```
let rows = [
  { row1: [{ val: "row1-val1" }, { val: "row1-val2" }] },
  { row1: [{ val: "row1-val3" }, { val: "row1-val4" }] },
  { row1: [{ val: "row1-val5" }, { val: "row1-val6" }] },
  { parag: { text: "sample test" } },
  { row2: [{ val: "row2-val1" }, { val: "row2-val2" }] },
  { row2: [{ val: "row2-val3" }, { val: "row2-val4" }] },
  { row2: [{ val: "row2-val5" }, { val: "row2-val6" }] }
];
```

i want this result:

```
let rows = [
  {
    row1: [
      { val: "row1-val1" },
      { val: "row1-val2" },
      { val: "row1-val3" },
      { val: "row1-val4" },
      { val: "row1-val5" },
      { val: "row1-val6" }
    ]
  },
  { parag: { text: "sample test" } },
  {
    row2: [
      { val: "row2-val1" },
      { val: "row2-val2" },
      { val: "row2-val3" },
      { val: "row2-val4" },
      { val: "row2-val5" },
      { val: "row2-val6" }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with help of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let rows = [{ row1: [{ val: "row1-val1" }, { val: "row1-val2" }] },{ row1: [{ val: "row1-val3" }, { val: "row1-val4" }] },{ row1: [{ val: "row1-val5" }, { val: "row1-val6" }] },{ parag: { text: "sample test" } },{ row2: [{ val: "row2-val1" }, { val: "row2-val2" }] },{ row2: [{ val: "row2-val3" }, { val: "row2-val4" }] },{ row2: [{ val: "row2-val5" }, { val: "row2-val6" }] }];

let op = rows.reduce((o,c)=>{
  let key = Object.keys(c)[0];
  if(o[key]){
    o[key].push(...c[key]);
  } else {
    o[key] = c[key];
  }
  return o;
},{})

console.log(op)
```